# Django - Model - Is it possible to use dict key value in UniqueConstraint combined with other attributes

Tags: django, django-models, unique-constraint

Short version of the question: Is it possible to use dict key value in `UniqueConstraint`. If not, advice on implementing the logic described;

*I use postgreSql

In django, I have a model which;

has a name attribute which is an [I18nCharField](https://django-i18nfield.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html) meaning, on the form, for the name attribute there are two inputs, one for english and one for portuguese. Other attributes are like below.

**Unique Constraints:** (second one is the problem here) Acronym and Code can be null. This is why I have these `UniqueConstraints` with query in here. But the involvement of the name should be based on only the portuguese version. English one can be even blank. (name is mandatory but only the portuguese one)

What my problem is; this name field is being saved as:

> {"en": "record5-level3", "pt": "registro5-nível3"}

meaning, I cannot use this in the Unique Constraints as it is because someone can just use the same portuguese name and put random stuff in the english input. I cannot keep uniqueness on the pt name with other attributes. What I want to do is; customize this unique constraints in order to consider name as its pt value inside, or use the `UniqueConstraints` with `name.pt`

Is it possible? Or any other suggestion to implement the logic here? Thanks in advance.

```
class ScientificArea(models.Model):

    code = models.CharField(verbose_name=_("Code"), blank=True, max_length=255)
    acronym = models.CharField(verbose_name=_("acronym"), blank=True, max_length=25)
    name = I18nCharField(
        verbose_name=_("Name"), blank=False, max_length=255
    )
    parent = models.ForeignKey(
        "self",
        verbose_name=_("Scientific Area Parent"),
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        related_name="Scientific Area Children",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    hierarchy_type = models.ForeignKey(
        ScientificAreaTypes, blank=False, null=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("Scientific Area")
        verbose_name_plural = _("Scientific Areas")
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(
                name='scientific_area_hierarchy_name_acronym_code_uniq',
                fields=('hierarchy_type', 'name', 'code', 'acronym')
            ), models.UniqueConstraint(
                name='portuguese_name_uniq',
                fields=('name',),
                condition=Q(designacao__contains={"pt": ""}), # problem here, how to do this?
            ), models.UniqueConstraint(
                name='scientific_area_hierarchy_name_code_null_acronym_null_uniq',
                fields=('hierarchy_type', 'name', 'code', 'acronym'),
                condition=Q(code__isnull=True) | Q(acronym__isnull=True)
            )
        ]
```

- I can only think of dealing with this in the model's `clean()` which does not sound so cool. Or having another attribute for the name that would not be on the form but I would fetch the portuguese name and make it equal to that to use it in the `UniqueConstraints`

Answer (score 0):

You might be overcomplicating this slightly, could you not simply create a new `ScientificAreaTypes` object which is actually `NULL`?

So in essence there is a relationship, but it allows you to exclude `ScientificArea` objects which have the `NULL` relationship?

Best part is that this can create a unique constraint even on the pseudo `NULL` object if that makes sense?

**UPDATE**

```py
ScientificAreaTypes.objects.create(name='NULL', acronym='NULL')
```

Then you can make a constraint across the pseudo NULL object.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand. What do you mean by creating a new object which is actually null?

Comment: I can expand on my answer if you share this model please: `ScientificAreaTypes`

Comment: ´ScientificAreaTypes´ is a model with two charField attributes, name and acronym thats all.

Comment: @Flardryn please see my update, hope this makes it clearer what I was trying to explain :)

Comment: Not sure what I am missing here. The idea here is having a unique ScientificArea in one ScientificAreaType. But the name has translations and kept as a dict. I want to focus on one language in the dict to provide the uniqueness. I don't understand how having a null type object will help. This is why I was wondering if it is possible to have a query UniqueConstraint to deal that. Otherwise my best solution is adding another attribute in the model that would copy the pt key from the dict. I need a bit more detail how to use this if this will provide the logic.